# How to get a list of jobs from custom View

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I extend ListView in Java.
And trying to get a list of added jobs to that view. Here is what I have

MyExtendedView.java and index.jelly

```
 public class MyExtendedView extends ListView {

      public static final class SomeDescriptor extends ViewDescriptor {
        //some code omited
        public ArrayList<Job> jobs () {
           //here I hope to get a list of Jobs that user added to this view
           //Jobs can be added when creating the view it is inherited 
           //functionality from LisView
        }
      }
 }
```

One way to do it to pass parameter from index.jelly
but is there a way to get it from here directly using TopLevelItems ?

Comment: Please add a lot more detail - as it is, it's very unclear what you're asking. Show some code, show what isn't working the way you want or an attempt at solving your problem. We can't see your screen or understand your situation if you don't tell us about it

Answer (score 0):

${h.getAllTopLevelItems(it.ownerItemGroup)}